# Extending classes and overriding properties in a C# .NET constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a PHP programmer by default, and I need a little help with a C# .NET (Micro Frameworks, but that doesn't matter here) project.

Basically, I have a class that allows for control of an RC car or airplane speed controller. The class is already written, but I need a way to import settings into the class, since diffident electric speed controllers require different settings.

My ideal set up would be something like this:

```
SpeedController esc = new SpeedController(SpeedControllers.TRAXXAS_XL5);
```

I know how the constructor and all that work, but how do I configure the SpeedControllers.TRAXXAS_XL5 part? I would create a base class (Speedcontrollers) and then a class that extends it, overriding the default values, correct?

Can someone direct me to a tutorial on what I am talking about or a small code snippet of a child class overriding properties in a parent class?

Comment: Is SpeedControllers an enum or a set of SpeedController singletons?  What exactly is the type of SpeedControllers.TRAXXAS_XL5?

Comment: I was thinking that TRAXXAS_XL5 would be a class extending SpeedControllers and overriding a series of settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just take an example using a hypothetical `MaxSpeed` the conroller might have.

```
abstract class SpeedControllers {
    public abstract int MaxSpeed { get; }

    public class TRAXXAS_XL5 : SpeedControllers{
        public override int MaxSpeed {
            get {
                return 30;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your SpeedController constructor

```
class SpeedController {
    readonly SpeedControllers properties;
    public SpeedController(SpeedControllers properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    public int MaxSpeed {
        get {
            return properties.MaxSpeed;
        }
    }
 }
```

Call it with `new SpeedController(new SpeedControllers.TRAXXAS_XL5())`

Answer (score 2):

IMO, best way to do that would be something like this:

```
public struct SpeedControllers {
    int speed;
    int etc;

    public SpeedControllers(int s, int e) {
        speed = s;
        etc = e;
    }

    public const SpeedControllers TRAXXAS_XL5 = new SpeedControllers(123, 345);
    public const SpeedControllers WHATEVER = new SpeedControllers(456, 789);
}
```

And, have the `SpeedController` constructor read the values out of the struct. Obviously, add/customize the fields as necessary.

DISCLAIMER: I haven't run this through the compiler, only through my brain. Do not attempt to fly an actual airplane with this as is ;)

Comment: lol for the disclaimer, although I have a feeling that SpeedControllers.TRAXXAS_XL5 refers to an internal class/struct, or perhaps an enum.

Comment: This is in no way meant a knock against the CLR. Windows, or Microsoft but please don't use the Micro Framework on any critical component of a "real" airplane... It's not a realtime OS. As for your code you should probably consider static readonly over a constant.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not for an airplane. If it was, it wouldn't be on NETMF

Comment: @Robert: I get the impression that we're coming up with new code here. I.e., there is no existing TRAXXAS_XL5 struct.

Answer (score 1):

If SpeedControllers.TRAXXAS_XL5 is nothing but configuration *data* (i.e., all numeric values) then I wouldn't consider this an optimal example of derived classes.

Yes, you can create a base class (SpeedController) which contains the properties and perhaps default values. Then you could create derived classes that override.

Instead, what Mike Caron has demonstrated is using the *same* class and simply using initialization of the data to create the various specialized *instances* of the controller class. I would recommend something like that (perhaps loading the values from an external file if you want to make it easy to configure).

Comment: But what if there are three different ways to instantiate a SpeedController? I don't imagine this would work very well for makes and models of vehicles, but it might work if you want to differentiate a train `SpeedController` from a truck `SpeedController`, and set up some default object characteristics accordingly.

Comment: I can't load from file, it's embedded. I would generally agree, that yes, this would be something that should NOT be hard coded, but in this case, it is.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-cbitmap.aspx (Read the comments, and then roll your eyes)

Comment: Jeez, it's like the Godwin's law of TDWTF